# Lambda updateFunctionCode is ridiculously slow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm deploying my lambda function code through Lambda.`updateFunctionCode` (zip 44mb).
It works fine for the first time (updates within 2 min).
But after that when I re-upload the code with some changes, it doesn't work.
Timeout error is -

```
message: 'Connection timed out after 120000ms',
code: 'TimeoutError',
time: 2018-07-05T05:40:41.951Z,
region: 'us-east-1',
hostname: 'lambda.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
retryable: true
```

Also, I tried uploading the zip to s3, unfortunately, it didn't work too. It was showing around 10-20kbpps speed and failed.

> I think AWS is kind of blocking/restricting my IP or something. It happened twice on different days(first upload works and fails after)
>
> So my question is how can I fix it and why this is happening?

My code to update lambda function code looks like this -

```
fs.readFile("./" + functionName + ".zip", function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
       console.log(err);
       return;
    }
    console.log(' deploying ...' + functionName);

    var params = {
      FunctionName: functionName,
      Publish: false,
      ZipFile: new Buffer(data)
    };
    if(functionAlias === 'DEV' || functionAlias === 'PROD'){
        params.Publish = true;
    }
    lambda.updateFunctionCode(params, function(err, data) {
       if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return;
       }
       console.log(' deployed ...' + functionName);
    });
});
```

Comment: What is your question now?

Comment: Why this is happening and what's the solution. thanks.

Comment: You are uploading function code for a AWS Lambda inside a AWS Lambda? May I ask you why? Which runtime are you using? Could you show some code examples?

Comment: @MaiKaY I've written a script which create a zip of the lambda code and uploads it to lambda. Find this documentation for function https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#updateFunctionCode-property 
I have also attached my code structure in my question now. thanks for mentioning.

Comment: Okay, so you are NOT uploading the code inside a AWS Lambda. You are uploading it from your local machine... I suggest to test your upload speed of your internet connection. If it seems to be "normal" try a different upload approach: e.g. use `aws-cli`

Comment: So I tested it a couple of times in last 2 days. The weird situation that it works for the first time and doesn't for next frequent attempt is confusing. I just tried (which is 2 hours after my last failed attempt) and it worked.